# AWK not working in ubuntu distribution 14

Tags: ubuntu, awk

The fallowing is query that was running properly on my redhat, when i executed the same in ubuntu its giving syntax error.

Query :

```
  $ ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'match($0, /src ([0-9.]+)/, a)  { print a[1] }'
```

Redhat : 192.168.190.82

Ubuntu : error in awk first line ,

Comment: post the output of `ip route get 8.8.8.8` command.

Comment: Solution : we just need to install gawk for that to work.

Answer (score 3):

Solution : we just need to install gawk for that to work.

```
     sudo apt-get install gawk
```

Comment: Yes, once gawk is installed it will become the default awk. Your `match` was using a gnu extension not available on standard awk

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd arg to match() is a gawk extension. Just change it to:

```
awk 'match($0, /src ([0-9.]+)/)  { print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4) }'
```

and it'll work on any awk.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through  awk(mawk) like below,

```
awk -v RS= '{print gensub(/.*src ([0-9.]+).*/, "\\1", $0);}'
```

Example:

```
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk -v RS= '{print gensub(/.*src ([0-9.]+).*/, "\\1", $0);}'
192.168.190.82
```

Comment: gensub() is not basic (POSIX), it's another GNU awk extension which is now showing up in mawk too but it won't work in other awks.